# Yii2 Catching Exceptions in Console Mode

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, yii2

I am trying to add some error catching blocks in my Console app.

Specifically for example I have a SQL code block,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM
          visits_column_maps";
$mapsAry = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

If something goes south an exception is thrown and the script ends.

I would like to catch this and end it on my terms.

I tried a try/catch block;

```
try {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM
              visits_column_maps";
    $mapsAry = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
} catch(Exception @e) {
    // graceful exit here
    echo "Exception caught";
    exit();
}
```

but when tested by changing the table name I still get a script termination prior to catching it.

I suppose I may need to adjust a configuration somewhere but not really sure where.

Thanks for any help provided.
Scotty

Comment: you need to use `\Exception` instead of `Exception` class

Comment: @Sr1871 you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `\Exception` instead of `Exception`

```
try {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM
              visits_column_maps";
    $mapsAry = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // graceful exit here
    echo "Exception caught";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: whats with `\Exception @e`? don't you think it should be `\Exception $e`? it would be a syntax error

Comment: You're right, there is no sense avoid errors in try\catch

Comment: Thanks so very much Sr1871 for your time and answer.  And yeah the @e was a typo in the post but good eye Aslam.